# Azure does not read web.config settings

Tags: azure, web-config, web-deployment

<strike>I have to deploy my (old school) application to Azure using the Web deployment tools/Azure Web Accelerator. I'm not an Azure pro and I havn't set up the whole Azure Publishing enviroment.
Still i can publish my application with Visualstudio to Azure. Never the less when I try System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setting"] I get an empty value.
Local on the webapplication I get a value.</strike>

So I know that 'RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable' is true and localy isn't still that's the only lead I have. Any help is welcome

Thanks guys but I've fixed it. It's quite simple after all. The Azure Web Accelerator was configured at url service.test.com the site which couldn't read the web.config was a the same base url only a virtual application like service.test.com/shop.

When I changed the service.test.com/shop to run at testshop.shopname.com everything worked. So basicly you can't run both web app/sites on the same url.

Comment: You're not accessing this from the RoleEntryPoint are you?

Comment: Nope just the normal old fashioned way by ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

Answer (score 0):

If it's OK when using the local simulator? You could RDP to your windows azure virtual machine to have a look on the web.config directly. About how to use RDP on windows azure please have a look

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx

http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/12/03/remote-desktop-to-your-azure-virtual-machine.aspx

Comment: I can asure you the web.config has been deployed correctly. I've also configured the virtual machine so my deployed site was able to run localhost. Then the web.config was properly read. Which I find very strange. When the binding to localhost was removed the web.config failed to be read